# Qt packaging for windows platform

Tags: windows, qt, windows-installer, packager

I'm looking for Qt packager for my Qt application targeted for windows platform.
 I need it to create a nice installer to deploy and distribute my product on windows PC.
Which is best and recommended FREE packager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For packaging I use the [WIX (Windows Installer XML) toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

There are several advantages to using WIX:

- Free and open-source
- Creates MSI files, which allows your application to be easily deployed across large networks and correctly uninstalls (also very important)
- Supported and developed by Microsoft, it is used by several other Microsoft teams internally, e.g the [Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2011/10/24/WiX-v3.6-Beta-released) installer features some of the latest WIX features
- XML configuration allows reuse of components of installers (sets of files, feature sets)
- Several types of user interface, new wizard pages can be created
- Integrates into Visual Studio
- Integrates into MSBuild - can allow consistent packaging to ensure you don't ship debug versions

I have used WIX for installers at work and for my own projects at home.

It isn't as simple as other solutions to get started, but once you've created a simple package, you'll find it easy to add new features.

Answer (score 3):

NSIS is the way to go in my opinion.  Straight forward scripting, compatible with all Microsoft Operating Systems and with support for User Levels.

Plus it has a huge active forum for any specific help you may need.  I use the HMNSIS editor to write the scripts and have not come across anything it hasn't been able to do yet!

Answer (score 2):

Qt has nothing that can help you, but *the* free Windows installer package creator is without a doubt [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

Answer (score 2):

Inno Setup is a another good, free, light-weight installer system.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Qt Installer Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/).  That is a link to the manual for it.  It is multi-platform.  With it, you write XML files in a directory structure for delivery of components in the directories, called packages.  It has scripting.  You then compile it into a setup for your target platform.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I was under the impression that they did not make it available to users of the Community edition until recent versions.  When the earlier replies were written, it may well have been commercial version only.

Alas, nothing seems to warn you that you have to collect up components, nor tell you what they are, or even talk about the process; except that the 3rd. party, but free (Windows only), [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can tell you what dynamic libraries are being used.  I don't find it a necessity, but it can be helpful.  (Tip: On Windows anyway, be sure to put "qwindows.dll" in a "platforms" directory with the exe.  Tip #2: Make sure the Qt DLL's or static libraries are ones compiled for your compiler.)